# What is the probability that $A,B,C$ are independent

Tags: probability, statistics

My lecturer posed a question in class which I have tried to solve with no success, any help would be much appreciated.

Let $\Omega = {1,2,3,...,n}$ be the sample space.
Choose 3 events randomly: A,B,C such that $A,B,C \subseteq P(\Omega)$ where $P(\Omega)$ denotes the power set. What is the probability that A,B and B,C and A,C are all independent?

We are taking the uniform distribution on $\Omega$ and on $P(\Omega)$

Comment: normally events are independent or they are not. $A$ and $B$ are independent iff $P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B) $. If the events _themselves_ are random, what distribution are we drawing them from? Are we choosing the events uniformly at random?

Comment: The events are random. Would it be possible to find the possibility that $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$?

Comment: You need to specify two things before we can answer the question. 1. What is the probability distribution over $\Omega$ (in order to answer things like "what is $P(\{1,3,4\})$?")?, and 2. How are the three events chosen?

Comment: Thank you @angryavain, the probability that a single number appears in $1/n$ and so $P({(1,3,4)}) = 3/n$. In addition, all three events are chosen randomly

Comment: @Davidross so, you are actually taking the uniform distribution on $\Omega$ and on $\mathscr{P}(\Omega)?$

Comment: Exactly. @Will M.

Comment: This will be heavily dependent on the multiplicative structure of $n$, suggesting there will not necessarily be a "nice" closed formula.  For example, you can rewrite the event "$A$ and $B$ are independent" as "$|A| |B| = n |A \cap B|$.  If $n$ is prime, then this can only happen if at least one of $A$ and $B$ are either empty or the complete set (because you need $|A| |B|$ to be a multiple of $n$, which can only happen if one of $|A|$ or $|B|$ is).  But if $n$ is composite, there are other solutions.  This is particularly noticeable if $n$ has small square factors (continued in next comment).

Comment: For example, if $n$ is a multiple of $4$, you now have the possibility that $|A| = |B| = n/2$ and $|A \cap B| = n/4$.  If $n$ is large, then this is far more likely than one of the sets being empty.  So independent sets are much more common when $n$ is a multiple of $4$ than when it is not.

Comment: A,B,C are event so $A,B,C \in P(\Omega)$  not $A,B,C \subseteq P(\Omega)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, we can slightly generalize the formula for the number of pairs of independent subsets over a set of $n$ elements to a formula for the number of triples of pairs of independent subsets, but it involves a lot of factorials and a lot of nested sums.

For reference, here are the first few answers for the number of triples of events that are pairwise independent.

```
# TRIPLES
0 (1, 1)
1 (8, 8)
2 (32, 64)
3 (80, 512)
4 (368, 4096)
5 (368, 32768)
6 (5072, 262144)
7 (1520, 2097152)
8 (211376, 16777216)
```

The same problem with pairs seems easier to tackle, so let's look at that first.

So, we can count up the number of ordered pairs of two events $A,B$ on $n$ elements with each element being equally likely using a simple Python program (omitted).

The first couple of counts are given in this table (the second element of each pair is the denominator).

```
# PAIRS
0 (1, 1)
1 (4, 4)
2 (12, 16)
3 (28, 64)
4 (84, 256)
5 (124, 1024)
6 (972, 4096)
7 (508, 16384)
8 (8020, 65536)
9 (17164, 262144)
10 (130092, 1048576)
11 (8188, 4194304)
```

This corresponds to [this sequence on OEIS](https://oeis.org/A121312).

The formula given is:

$$ \sum_{u=0}^{n} \;\;\sum_{(a,b) \in [u,n]} [ab=nu] \binom{n}{a} \binom{a}{u} \binom{n-a}{b-u} $$

This formua has a straightforward combinatorial interpretation:

$a$ is the number of items in $A$ and $b$ is the number of items in $B$. $u*n$ is the size of the intersection of $A \land B$ in a larger sample space consisting of pairs of elements of $\Omega$ .

if we know, $a$, $b$, and $u$, the size of the intersection -- then we have to pick which elements are in $a$, given by $\binom{n}{a}$, which elements of $a$ are in the intersection, and which elements in the complement of $a$ are outside the intersection.

It can also be written like this, which makes the combinatorial intepretation more clear.

$$ \sum_{u=0}^{n} \;\;\sum_{(a,b) \in [u,n]} [ab=nu] \frac{n!}{u!(a-u)!(b-u)!(n-a-b+u)!} $$

We are considering all possible permutations of $n$, and then dividing out by the number of rearrangements in each of four "buckets": both $A$ and $B$, $A$ but not $B$, $B$ but not $A$, and neither $A$ nor $B$.

We also disregard the cases where the putative size of the intersection $u$ is not equal to the product of $a$ and $b$ divided by the size of $\Omega$.

We can use this trick ourselves if we know the size of the intersection of $A$ and $B$ and $C$ in addition to the size of the pairwise intersections.

First, I'm going to define the function $f(x;a_1,a_2,b_3)$ which is

$$ f(x;a_1\dots a_n) = \frac{x!}{a_1! \dots a_n!} $$
$$ f(x;a_1\dots a_n) = 0 \;\;\;\text{if any $a$s are negative} $$

Our formula is the following ... which falls transparently out of the principle of inclusion-exclusion. All we're doing is counting the number of ways to partition $n$ into different chunks and throwing out the cases where $a$, $b$, and $c$ aren't independent by using a product of Iverson brackets $[ab=nu][bc=nv][ca=nw]$ .

$$ \sum_{z=0}^{n} \sum_{u=z}^{n} \sum_{v=z}^{n} \sum_{w=z}^{n} \sum_{a=u}^{n} \sum_{b=v}^{n} \sum_{c=w}^{n} [ab=nu][bc=nv][ca=nw] \\
f\left(n\;;\begin{pmatrix} z \\ u-z \\ v-z \\ w-z \\ a-u-w+z \\ b-v-u+z \\ c-w-v+z \\ n-a-b-c+u+w+v-z\end{pmatrix}\right) $$

Appendices -- Source code. This code is somewhat slapdash and uses multiple nested for loops instead of cartesian products of iterators or other, more elegant abstractions. *However*, the code does map onto the expressions given above fairly well.

Appendix I: Brute Force tally of number of triples of pairwise independent events over $n$ elements.

```
from random import *
from itertools import *

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

def rand_subset(n):
    out = []
    for x in range(n):
        if randint(0, 1) == 0:
            out.append(x)
    return out

def is_independent(x, y, n):
    intersection_len = len(set(x).intersection(set(y)))
    prod_len = len(x) * len(y)
    return prod_len == intersection_len * n


assert is_independent([0,1], [0,2], 4)


def count(n):
    tally = 0
    for x in powerset(range(n)):
        for y in powerset(range(n)):
            for z in powerset(range(n)):
                if is_independent(x, y, n) and is_independent(y, z, n) and is_independent(x, z, n):
                    tally += 1
    return (tally, (2**n) ** 3)

for x in range(12):
    print(x, count(x))
```

Appendix II: slightly smarter inclusion-exclusion tally

```
import math
factorial = math.factorial

def choose(n, k):
    return math.factorial(n) // math.factorial(k) // math.factorial(n-k)

def multifact(num, denoms):
    assert sum(denoms) == num
    if min(denoms) < 0:
        return 0
    prod = factorial(num)
    for d in denoms:
        f = factorial(d)
        assert (prod % f == 0)
        prod //= f
    return prod

def formula(n):
    tally = 0
    for z in range(0,n+1):
        for u in range(z,n+1):
            for v in range(z,n+1):
                for w in range(z, n+1):
                    for a in range(u, n+1):
                        for b in range(v, n+1):
                            for c in range(w, n+1):
                                if a*b != n * u:
                                   continue
                                if b*c != n * v:
                                   continue
                                if c*a != n * w:
                                   continue
                                tally += multifact(
                                    n,
                                    [z, u-z, v-z, w-z, a-u-w+z, b-v-u+z, c-w-v+z, n-a-b-c+u+w+v-z]
                                )
    return tally

for x in range(12):
    print((x, formula(x)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much